# Wordpress permission issue on a fresh install of CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, installation, permissions

I have just installed CiviCRM and I have a permission issue when accessing the "Configuration checklist" page.

When clicked, this URL redirects me to front-end with message :

> "You do not have permission to access this content."

**Page URL** : http://domain.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/configtask&reset=1

How come I encounter this issue ? 
Can it be a server-side configuration problem ?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.7 and having the same issue.

Comment: Just installed 4.7.14 and got the same error. I can access the configuration checklist from the admin menu but his error is annoying and as mentioned in one of the answer below, it may be a result of some faulty logic in civicrm.users.php.

Answer (score 1):

I have around  workaround for this issue - not an answer or fix to the permissions problem though....

If you scroll to the footer of the page and click on the "System Status: error" link.

http://localhost/xxxxxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/a/#/status)

This will take to the config checklist screen.

Still need an answer to the permissions issue though - where do I set permissions for the config checklist page, and why would they have changed if I have not upgraded anything?

Answer (score 1):

The message "You do not have permission to access this content." is being issued as a result of the logic in `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.users.php`. This file is new in 4.6. A variable `$invalidPaths` is being used in an unexpected way.

`public function check_permission( $args ) {
    if ( $args[0] != 'civicrm' ) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
    // set frontend true
    $config->userFrameworkFrontend = TRUE;
    require_once 'CRM/Utils/Array.php';
    // all profile and file urls, as well as user dashboard and tell-a-friend are valid
    $arg1 = CRM_Utils_Array::value(1, $args);
    $invalidPaths = array('admin'); // So what is this for? Denying admin some rights? Why?
    if ( in_array( $arg1, $invalidPaths ) ) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }`

I don't know what was intended, but I interpret it to mean "if you're admin you're not authorized" - which is the opposite of what one would normally expect.  If you invert the logic or replace the array containing 'admin' with an empty array you get to see your checklist (at your own risk :))

I haven't tested to see if there are any adverse side effects of doing that and I don't know yet if this is an important bug.

Answer (score 0):

if you have recently updated to a newer version of civi, some of the permissions also have to be updated - while I don't remember this being the case for the configuration checklist page, this was the case for mailing templates for our clients.